# Make multiple histograms at once and save them

Tags: r, histogram

I would like to make histogram of columns 5-34 of my data set and save them for reference. This is what I have and the error 'x must be numeric' is what keeps coming up. All of these columns have numeric data.

[data screenshot][1]

```
dput(longbroca)
histograms = c()
GBhistograms = c()
RThistograms = c()
for (i in 5:34){

  hist(longbroca)
  hist(GBlongbroca)
  hist(RTlongbroca)

  histograms = c(histograms, hist(longbroca[,5:34]))
GBhistograms = c(GBhistograms, hist(GBlongbroca[,5:34]))
RThistograms = c(RThistograms, hist(RTlongbroca[,5:34]))

}

#reproducible
fakerow1 <- c(100,80,60,40,20)
fakerow2 <- c(100,80,60,40,20)
fakedata = rbind(fakerow1,fakerow2)
colnames(fakedata) = c('ant1','ant2','ant3','ant4','ant5')
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data via the ``dput()`` function please?

Comment: You are not using `i` to reference particular columns. Do you mean `hist(longbroca[,i])` etc?

Comment: sample of data added, I added ```hist(longbroca[,i])``` and I get the same error

Comment: Usually people copy the console output of dput() into a block of code.Or put some simulated data into a block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot plot all of the columns with a single `hist()` function. That is why you are getting the error message. You are plotting histograms and saving the output list from the histogram. Your code does not save any histograms, only the data for producing them. If you actually want to save the plotted histograms, you need to plot them to a device (e.g. pdf).

We can use the `iris` dataset which comes with R (`data(iris)`) as some example data. The first 4 columns are numeric. If you just want the data for the histograms from the `iris` data set (columns 1 through 4):

```
# R will plot all four but you will only see the last one.
histograms <- lapply(iris[, 1:4], hist)
```

The variable `histograms` is a list that contains 6 elements. These are documented on the manual page for the function (`?hist`).

```
# To plot one of the histograms with a title and x-axis label:
lbl <- names(histograms)
plot(histograms[[1]], main=lbl[1], xlab=lbl[1])

# To plot them all
pdf("histograms.pdf")
lapply(1:4, function(x) plot(histograms[[x]], main=lbl[x], xlab=lbl[x]))
dev.off()
```

The file "histograms.pdf" will have all four histograms, one per page.